# Receive NDI video stream in open cv

Tags: python, opencv

We have a videostream from camera with the help of NDI. How can we get it in OpenCV?

```
import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("tcp://192.168.1.69") 
while cap.isOpened(): 
_, frame = cap.read() 
# frame processing
```

We have tried the following variation of a string:

```
tcp://192.168.1.69 
tcp://192.168.1.69:8080 
http://192.168.1.69 
http://192.168.1.69:8080 
udp://192.168.1.69:8080
```

But we get an error every time. What is the correct string to use NDI stream?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late and I'm sure you may have already come across the solution.  You also failed to state the platform requirements. So the solution I have is currently Windows only at the moment.

The "NDI Virtual Input" driver allows an NDI network stream to be treated as a Webcam source.  Thus you can just set the video capture source to the ID of the device.  This requires the driver be installed on the client system

```
import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)  # Could be any number, it's system specific, but it's u=usually 0, 1 etc.
while cap.isOpened(): 
_, frame = cap.read() 
# frame processing
```

Comment: The platform I'm trying to use is a Jetson Nano (2GB version). In other words, Linux. It looks like NDI Virtual Input is still not supported on Linux... Do you have any alternative options?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PyNDI](https://github.com/CarlosFdez/pyNDI) - I added some examples there to show you how to get NDI into openCV.

The SimpleSourceViewer is command line based, the GUIExample uses TKInter to give you an interface.

Comment: For those trying to run PyNDI on Linux - you need to download NDI SDK and replace the DLL with libndi.so. Either rename it to where it pretends to be a DLL or just edit the code to use the so file instead. It was erroring out with incorrect ELF header for me.